# is there a way to make docker choose the available docker registry according to availablity?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

Is there a way to make docker chooses automatically the available registry to pull images from according to availability?

Comment: no, it's not designed for this. however you could use a reverse-proxy with some logic but I don't think it's wise as you should make your images pulled as fast as possible.

Comment: will this feature be granted if we used Kubernetes ?